# VkDescriptorPool limits and overhead?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan:

1. Multiple VkDescriptorPools can be created.
2. From each single VkDescriptorPool multiple VkDescriptorSets can be allocated.

Is there any limit to the number of VkDescriptorPools you can create? (apart from available memory)

Is there any indication in the spec of the overhead (memory, cpu-time, gpu-time) of using many small VkDescriptorPools versus using a few large ones?  Or doesn't it generally matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descriptor Pools are limited by memory (or at least that is the error code you get, no matter the underlying problem). Update-after-bind Desriptor Pools are limited by `maxUpdateAfterBindDescriptorsInAllPools`.

Vulkan specification usually does not comment on performance, as that might differ between GPUs or change in future GPUs.

Comment: It's true that the spec can't say in general what the costs are. The intended purpose and use of the object can give some indication though. Descriptor pools mostly exist to (a) provide a fast special-purpose allocator for descriptor sets, and (b) allow multiple threads to allocate descriptor sets without synchronization (mostly). Based on the creation parameters, you can expect that they probably pre-allocate space for the maximum descriptors allocatable from the pool. So the cost is mostly going to scale with the total number of descriptors in all the pools, rather than number of pools.